# css html ul menu with separator aligned with the container

Tags: html, css

for now i have generated the menu in this way:

```
nav{
width:1024px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

ul{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
border-right: 1.1px solid #333333;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 1em;
text-align: center;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis: initial;
text-align: center;
}
```

the html is:

```
<nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Training & Support</li>
                    <li>Templates & Forms</li>
                    <li>Policy Documents</li>
                    <li>Payment Administration</li>
                    <li>Tax Compliance</li>
                    <li>News</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

The result is:
[image]

But i want that the first and last child are aligned at the start and at the end of the ul container like in the image below

[image]

How can i do this?

Comment: Show your HTML.

Comment: @Soban  done! sorry

Comment: Please describe what you did so it might help someone else with the same problem.

Comment: remove padding-left for the first element and padding-right from the last one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `text-align: centre;` ???
Or in li try something like `padding-right: 0;`
Tell me how it works out.